# How to infer travel mode using a mobile phone?

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I am writing a travel optimization app. I would like to get some feedback on what would be the best way to decide which mode the user is currently using to travel i.e. walking, bicycle or vehicle.

Currently, I am using GPS data on a regular time interval (1 second) and calculating the distance travelled in that time interval. Based on the reasonable assumptions I have made on distance travelled in each mode, I can decide what the user is currently doing.

- Walking: 3 miles / hour
- Cycling: 15 miles / hour
- Vehicle: 20 miles / hour or higher

But to me this seems rather crude. Is there a better way?

Sensors available: GPS, Cameras, Accelerometer, Giro.

Note: I don't want to ask the user which mode they are using as that would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DetectedActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html) that should solve your problem. You may use ActivityRecognition[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition.html).

Comment: that is very helpful for android. Anything similar for ios?

Comment: I am also looking to understand the concept behind detecting it, so if you can offer some explanation that would be great as well.